# When is callback of Promise.all() triggered

Tags: javascript, promise

I just learned the concept of Promise.all() and am curious about its mechanism. From my limited knowledge of Promise, it passes a callback function in .then() method and invoke it in the definition. For instance:

```js
var p = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('4 sec function');
  }, 4000);
});

p.then(() => {
  console.log('2 sec function');
});
```

```
// result:
// 2 sec function
// 4 sec function
```

However, when we use `Promise.all()`, it triggers the callback when all promises fulfilled. As my guess, it triggers the callback in the promise which is fulfilled at last. In the instance below, my perspective of the result would be 'four'. However, it prints an array of the four numbers. Why does this happen? More specifically:

1. how many times is the callback actually triggered?
2. at which position in promises definition is the callback triggered?
3. what value is passed to the callback?

Here is the code I do research on:

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'one');
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'two');
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'three');
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, 'four');
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

```
// print:
// one
// two
// three
// four
```

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) tells you all you need to know

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX I am reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The callback is triggered once.
2. Either when all the promises are resolved or when one of them fails.
3. It receives an array of the values that all the promises resolved to.

Comment: So I can't imagine inserting the callback to somewhere in the code defining the promises right?

Comment: No. The whole point of `Promise.all()` is that you want to start a bunch of things and then do something when they all finish. That's why it's named "all".

Comment: @zhangjinzhou A use case for using Promise.all would be running multiple database methods at once...So that you don't have to wait for each to finish to trigger the next one (maybe that'll help you understand promise.all better). If I were to add multiple database methods at once, it'd mean that the callback method would contain ALL results from each of the db methods.

Answer (score 0):

**`Promise.race`**

There's also [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which will `resolve` or `reject` as soon as the **first** of the promises (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`, or `p4`) resolves or rejects

```js
// note: i've adjusted the delays from your original code
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, 'one');
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'two');
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'three');
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'four');
});

Promise.race([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(fastest => {
  console.log(fastest); // four
});
```

Comment: It's not evident to me that you actually have a problem. I'm providing this answer because I think it might be useful to you ^_^